# Handling output and exit codes of processes

Tags: java, multithreading, child-process

For a large, multi-threaded video processing application, I need to manage various child processes. I need to monitor their stdout and stderr.

My key concerns:

- I should not have any spin loops. I have a `Thread.sleep(10)` on my `inputHandler` (... which is actually a process output handler, but okay), but that's because it has to block until either the process has something new to say, or the process has exited.
- Methods not spawning a new thread should not block unless stated otherwise.
- Methods should be thread safe.
- Am I using too much threads?

I also implemented a listener that waits until a process dies, which will be used to schedule cleanup for any missed files and then to restart the process if needed. I did research as to what would be the best way to know when a thread dies, but all I found was "make the thread notify listeners as the last task". This introduces a vulnerability where if a thread dies, nobody is ever notified. And I don't trust all subclasses of `ProcessHandler` to never fail with handling output.

**ProcessListener**

```
public interface ProcessListener {
    public void onProcessEnd(ProcessHandler processEnded);
}
```

**ProcessHandler**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class ProcessHandler {
    private final Process process;
    private final BufferedReader stderr;
    private final BufferedReader stdin;
    private boolean stopSignalReceived = false;
    private final List<ProcessListener> processListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    private Thread inputHandler;

    public ProcessHandler(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
        stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        inputHandler = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                    handleInput();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // ignooore.
                    }
                } while (!hasStopped());
                // after stopping, check 1 last time for missed reads.
                handleInput();
            }

            private void handleInput(){
                try {
                    while (stderr.ready()) {
                        onStandardErr(stderr.readLine());
                    }
                    while (stdin.ready()) {
                        onStandardOut(stdin.readLine());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        inputHandler.start();
        final ProcessHandler instance = this;
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                do{
                    try{
                        inputHandler.join();
                        break;
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored){

                    }
                } while(true);
                synchronized(processListeners){
                    for(ProcessListener listener : processListeners){
                        listener.onProcessEnd(instance);
                    }
                }
            }

        }).start();
    }

    public void addListener(ProcessListener listenerToAdd){
        processListeners.add(listenerToAdd);
    }

    protected abstract void onStandardOut(String line);

    protected abstract void onStandardErr(String line);

    public Integer getExitValue() {
        try {
            return process.exitValue();
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasStopped() {
        return getExitValue() != null;
    }

    public boolean isStopping() {
        return stopSignalReceived || hasStopped();
    }

    /**
     * Blocking - Waits for the managed process to end.
     * Returns early if the process has not stopped and has not been given a signal to stop either.
     * Recommended usage is to call stop first.
     */
    public void waitForOutputProcessing() {
        if (!isStopping()) {
            return;
        }
        do {
            try {
                inputHandler.join();
                return;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (!stopSignalReceived) {
            stopSignalReceived = true;
            if (!hasStopped()) {
                if (process.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.UNIXProcess")) {
                    sendKillCommand();
                } else {
                    process.destroy();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void sendKillCommand() {
        try {
            final Field pidField = process.getClass().getDeclaredField("pid");
            pidField.setAccessible(true);
            final int pid = pidField.getInt(process);
            final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
            builder.command("kill", "" + pid);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Process killProcess = null;
                    do {
                        try {
                            if (hasStopped()) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (killProcess == null) {
                                killProcess = builder.start();
                            }
                            killProcess.waitFor();
                            process.waitFor();
                            return;
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // Ignore interrupts. Continue retrying to murder
                            // ffmpeg process.
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // IO error occurred.
                            if (!hasStopped()) {
                                throw new IllegalStateException("Process (Process ID: " + pid + ") failed to be killed.", e);
                            }
                            return;
                        }
                    } while (true);
                }

            }).start();

        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            process.destroy();// So we don't know the PID. Guess the only way to
                                // progress is to just kill FFMPEG.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `// TODO Auto-generated catch block` well, that's one line that could go...